# Use javascript to inject script references as needed?

Tags: javascript, include

I have a JS function that may occasionally get used on some pages. It is dependent on another JS file (swfObject.js), but I'd like to avoid having to include this file all over the place, as thats a wasted request most of the time.

Instead, I'd like to create a generic function that can inject a script reference into the page DOM as needed, so if this function is called, it would check for the script, and if it does not exist, load it in.

I'm fairly sure this is possible (and I'm not going to use document.write), but before I venture off into uncharted territory, has anyone done this before, and if so, any pointers?

EDIT: Ok, I tried it, and it works in IE6 and FF, I haven't tested other browsers yet.

Here is my code (Rev 2.0, now with optional callbacks):

```
function loadJSInclude(scriptPath, callback)
{
    var scriptNode = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    scriptNode.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptNode.src = scriptPath;

    var headNode = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD');
    if (headNode[0] != null)
        headNode[0].appendChild(scriptNode);

    if (callback != null)    
    {
        scriptNode.onreadystagechange = callback;            
        scriptNode.onload = callback;
    }
}
```

and in the method with a dependency:

```
var callbackMethod = function ()
{
    // Code to do after loading swfObject
}

// Include SWFObject if its needed
if (typeof(SWFObject) == 'undefined')    
    loadJSInclude('/js/swfObject.js', callbackMethod);
else
    calbackMethod();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand why this is necessary - once it has been requested for any page in your website/app, it is mostly likely cached anyway, so it really isn't hurting anything. Seems like a lot of extra effort for so little in return.

Comment: Jason, we have hundreds of files where this snippet might be used, so I'd prefer to have the ability to do this on the client (through our CMS system) instead of having to rebuild the site to add the script reference in the .CS file.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a higher level framework such as JQuery, you could check out the `$.getScript(url, callback)` function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your code on the very next line and like to write something like:

```
if (iNeedSomeMore){
  Script.load("myBigCodeLibrary.js");  // includes code for myFancyMethod();
  myFancyMethod();                     // cool, no need for callbacks!
}
```

There is a smart way to inject script dependencies *without the need of callbacks*. You simply have to pull the script via a *synchronous AJAX request* and eval the script on global level.

If you use Prototype the Script.load method looks like this:

```
var Script = {
  _loadedScripts: [],
  include: function(script){
    // include script only once
    if (this._loadedScripts.include(script)){
      return false;
    }
    // request file synchronous
    var code = new Ajax.Request(script, {
      asynchronous: false, method: "GET",
      evalJS: false, evalJSON: false
    }).transport.responseText;
    // eval code on global level
    if (Prototype.Browser.IE) {
      window.execScript(code);
    } else if (Prototype.Browser.WebKit){
      $$("head").first().insert(Object.extend(
        new Element("script", {type: "text/javascript"}), {text: code}
      ));
    } else {
      window.eval(code);
    }
    // remember included script
    this._loadedScripts.push(script);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I prefer my method, plus my method works for cross domain scripts.

Comment: What's with all the browser sniffing?

Comment: You're right kangax! But I was not able to evaluate the returned code within the global "window" scope. Especially WebKit messed up some things.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the YUI Loader utility.  It's super handy, unobtrusive javascript for loading scripts on-demand.

Here's a link to an example using non-YUI scripts:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/yuiloader/yl-addmodule.html

Answer (score 0):

None of these methods, including document.writing a script tag, work if the script itself has a document.write in it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple module that automatizes the job of importing/including module scripts in JavaScript. Give it a try and please spare some feedback! :) For detailed explanation of the code refer to this blog post: http://stamat.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/javascript-require-import-include-modules/

```
// ----- USAGE -----

require('ivar.util.string');
require('ivar.net.*');
require('ivar/util/array.js');
require('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js');

ready(function(){
    //do something when required scripts are loaded
});

    //--------------------

var _rmod = _rmod || {}; //require module namespace
_rmod.LOADED = false;
_rmod.on_ready_fn_stack = [];
_rmod.libpath = '';
_rmod.imported = {};
_rmod.loading = {
    scripts: {},
    length: 0
};

_rmod.findScriptPath = function(script_name) {
    var script_elems = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0; i < script_elems.length; i++) {
        if (script_elems[i].src.endsWith(script_name)) {
            var href = window.location.href;
            href = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('/'));
            var url = script_elems[i].src.substring(0, script_elems[i].length - script_name.length);
            return url.substring(href.length+1, url.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
};

_rmod.libpath = _rmod.findScriptPath('script.js'); //Path of your main script used to mark the root directory of your library, any library


_rmod.injectScript = function(script_name, uri, callback, prepare) {

    if(!prepare)
        prepare(script_name, uri);

    var script_elem = document.createElement('script');
    script_elem.type = 'text/javascript';
    script_elem.title = script_name;
    script_elem.src = uri;
    script_elem.async = true;
    script_elem.defer = false;

    if(!callback)
        script_elem.onload = function() {
            callback(script_name, uri);
        };

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_elem);
};

_rmod.requirePrepare = function(script_name, uri) {
    _rmod.loading.scripts[script_name] = uri;
    _rmod.loading.length++;
};

_rmod.requireCallback = function(script_name, uri) {
    _rmod.loading.length--;
    delete _rmod.loading.scripts[script_name];
    _rmod.imported[script_name] = uri;

    if(_rmod.loading.length == 0)
        _rmod.onReady();
};

_rmod.onReady = function() {
    if (!_rmod.LOADED) {
        for (var i = 0; i < _rmod.on_ready_fn_stack.length; i++){
            _rmod.on_ready_fn_stack[i]();
        });
        _rmod.LOADED = true;
    }
};

_.rmod = namespaceToUri = function(script_name, url) {
    var np = script_name.split('.');
    if (np.getLast() === '*') {
        np.pop();
        np.push('_all');
    }

    if(!url)
        url = '';

    script_name = np.join('.');
    return  url + np.join('/')+'.js';
};

//you can rename based on your liking. I chose require, but it can be called include or anything else that is easy for you to remember or write, except import because it is reserved for future use.
var require = function(script_name) {
    var uri = '';
    if (script_name.indexOf('/') > -1) {
        uri = script_name;
        var lastSlash = uri.lastIndexOf('/');
        script_name = uri.substring(lastSlash+1, uri.length);
    } else {
        uri = _rmod.namespaceToUri(script_name, ivar._private.libpath);
    }

    if (!_rmod.loading.scripts.hasOwnProperty(script_name) 
     && !_rmod.imported.hasOwnProperty(script_name)) {
        _rmod.injectScript(script_name, uri, 
            _rmod.requireCallback, 
                _rmod.requirePrepare);
    }
};

var ready = function(fn) {
    _rmod.on_ready_fn_stack.push(fn);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). This might need some rework of your frontend framework, but it's totally worth it. With require, you could just do the following in your `fileUsedOccasionally.js`:

```
define(['swfObject', 'someOtherDependency'], function (swfObject, someOtherDependency) {
  // you can now use swfObject as a JS object! you can call it whatever you want
  // you'll have to write a swfObject.js to wrap it with require
  // but that's trivial
});
```