# Reload javascript file realtime

Tags: javascript

I have a platform that I am using at the moment that uses js, css and php files.

What I would like to be able to achieve is to force the device to reload just specific Javascript files.

If I make a change to a js file on the server I don't wish to reboot the device just to load the javascript change.

for example if in a function in one of these pages I have an `alert('1');` and I wish to change this to `alert('2');` I don't want to have to reload the whole device

I have tried a few javascript update scripts that add the file into the head element with a tag of the current timestamp. this doesnt seem to work, I think it downloads the file yet still continues to us the old one.

I am sorry if this is really vague. Please ask any questions and I will try and answer them

Comment: what do you mean by rebooting the device to reload the files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "hot swap" JavaScript code within the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207513/is-there-a-way-to-hot-swap-javascript-code-within-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that 'phones home' every time and gets what it needs to do.

For your example, you can make a function that makes an XmlHttpRequest, and your server would give it a value of '1' or '2'.

To expand, you can also make your server return a block of javascript code, and `eval` it, but bear in mind that generally using `eval` is a bad idea (see [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea))

Answer (score 0):

How about this, at the moment you need to choose a js file to execute, you request the code by XMLHttpRequest. The code will be returned as string. Then use eval(code) to execute it. 
For example, eval("alert('2')");
But, eval is evil..

Answer (score 0):

Try this - worked for me. But remember to put this code as last part of body in you html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    var versionUpdate = (new Date()).getTime();
    var myscript = document.createElement("SCRIPT");  
    myscript.type = "text/javascript";  
    myscript.src = "scripname.js?v=" + versionUpdate;  
    document.body.appendChild(myscript);
</script>
```