# javascript "include" strategies

Tags: javascript

**Duplicate of:** [Use javascript to inject script references as needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203113/use-javascript-to-inject-script-references-as-needed)

Javascript doesn't have any directive to "include" or "import" another js file.
This means that if `script1.js` uses functions/objects defined in `script2.js`, then every html page that includes script1.js must include script2.js before it.

This shouldn't be a big problem if you only have 2 js files in like 10 html pages. I mean, it's manageable then!

But say suddenly you change `script1.js` and improve it by using functions/objects defined in a new file, `script3.js` 
The problem is, you can't just tell `script1.js` to include `script3.js`, instead, you have to remember every html file that included `script1.js` and update it to include `script3.js` as well!

This seems like rather stupid way of organizing code.

Are there recommended strategies or practices to deal with this issue?

Would it be acceptable to have a gigantic js file that holds all the functionality that you use across the website?

Comment: Reopened. This is not the first time it has been pointed out that you must put the duplicate you closed this for at the top of the question.

Comment: You could have fixed that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic includes:

[Use javascript to inject script references as needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203113/use-javascript-to-inject-script-references-as-needed)

Answer (score 1):

Scriptaculous (and probably other frameworks) handle this by writing script tags for the included files to the document when they are loaded.  Below is the relevant bit from the scriptaculous.js file that allows loading the other files in the framework.

```
 var Scriptaculous = {
   Version: '1.8.2',
   require: function(libraryName) {
     // inserting via DOM fails in Safari 2.0, so brute force approach
     document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+libraryName+'"><\/script>');
   },
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I try to avoid all this confusion by rolling all my javascript into one file. If there's one page which requires a LOT of javascript which the other pages don't need, then just have two files - generally the page-specific JS can be loaded after the generic js without hassles anyway.

To roll the JS files into one, I use Dean Edwards's Javascript Packer, combined with a helper script that I described on my [blog](http://spadgos.com/?p=32). It makes working with many JS files muuuuuch easier (for me at least), and the compression you get from packing the javascript is better.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could use document.write in your JS files to make sure they include whatever dependencies they're dependent upon, though I wouldn't really recommend it...