# Load js from external site on fly

Tags: javascript

I want to load JS code from external site when user click on button. For example:

```
 <button onclick="LoadJSFromURL('facebook.com/blablabla')" />
```

and when user press button we attach new script to the document:

```
<script> Share.WorkUrl="http://MySite.com"; Share.UserId=5 </script> <script src="http://Facebookcom/blabalbal" ></script>
```

and then we must execute this script. Is it real?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this : [How do you dynamically load a javascript file from different domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593419/how-do-you-dynamically-load-a-javascript-file-from-different-domain)

```
var script = new Element("script", {src: "myBigCodeLibrary.js", type: "text/javascript"});

script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (!this.readyState ||
        this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
        //script is loaded
    }
};
```

Comment: Does this solution depend on Prototype?