# Re-Executing a hardcoded external JavaScript in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have an ad script running, which is hardcoded into my HTML. Now I want to refresh that ad tag after 240 seconds. Easy way would be to simply load the ad tag in an iframe, and put a refresh on that, but iframes cannot be used in my case.

Right now the ad tag loads like this:

```
    <div class="banner_728">
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
            bb = new Object();
            bb.size = "728x90";
        //--></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//adserver.com/tags/tags.js"></script>
    </div>
```

How could I re-execute that javascript after a set amount of seconds, whilst leaving that ad-tag hardcoded into my site.

Comment: what do you mean by refreshing the "add tag"?

Comment: basically the ad gets executed again after 240 seconds

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738595/how-do-i-delay-a-function-call-for-5-seconds

Answer (score 1):

Apparently You'll need to load the Ad Server JS again.

```
var bb, created=false;
function reRun() { 
    bb = new Object();
    bb.size = "728x90";

    if(created) document.body.removeChild( document.getElementById("id-ads") );

    // try this instead
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = "//adserver.com/tags/tags.js";
    js.id = "id-ads";
    document.body.appendChild(js);

    created = true;

}
var TIMEOUT = setTimeout( reRun , 240 * 1000 );
reRun();
```

You may or may not have security issues loading external js on the fly. 
Please read this post which is going to be helpful for your needs:

[How do you dynamically load a javascript file from different domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593419/how-do-you-dynamically-load-a-javascript-file-from-different-domain)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think we are nearly there. I am getting an error though. "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor at reRun". Points to the 6th line in your example. The one starting with "var script".

Comment: Sorry, this is using PrototypeJS. Download here:
http://prototypejs.org/download/ or if you want plain js 
I've edited the answer, please test that ...